# I get an error when I try to import minerl

Tags: python, minecraft

I tried to make a AI for minecraft using python's library minerl.

```
import gym
import minerl

env = gym.make('MineRLObtainDiamond-v0')
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
self.shape = ()
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Can someone tell me why I get an error?

I run it on the latest python version, python 3.9.7, on Pycharm and I use Windows 10 build 19402.

Answer (score 0):

You have too new gym installed. Run the command:

`pip install gym==0.19` and try again.

https://github.com/minerllabs/minerl/issues/620